# tar (child): : Cannot open: Is a directory

Tags: directory, tar, bzip2, streams

I know thats a pretty dumb question but I didn't found this precise question on internet

I try to `tar -cvjf` all the contents of a directory (`/*`) and directly redirect that to a file (`> file`) but the title error message occurs. I compress both files and directories here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `tar` is

```
tar -f output input
```

So you want to run

```
tar -cvjf /path/to/output.tar.bz2 /what/you/want/to/compress
```

Comment: Yeah, it was pretty dumb, like I said